# nonblocking mongo shell command

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to move a large mongodb database (arround 400 gb) from one server to another. Both servers are in the same data center and I decided to use db.copyDatabase() for that.
Because of the db size, this will run several hours. When I begin a copy inside mongo shell, the prompt does not return until the copy is finished. Is there a way to run that command "asynchron". I want to close the ssh session to the destination server and therfor need the shell to not stop the copy when I exit it.

thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: The mongodb shell itself uses a "syncronous" driver command syntax. You can of course code that same command into a langauge driver that uses "async" function responses. **But**., what you are asking here actually requires a certain level of "database" or at least "collection" **locking** ( depending on the version and storage engine ). So the end result is *"The operation will take hours"*. Unless there is another way you can specify in an expansion to your question that would explain the conditions you could possibly deal with. Then there might be other ways to handle your "collection copy".

Comment: I know about the locking thing. I already tested it out and didnt experience a problem on production requests to the source database.
The database is currently on the same server as the frontend. I want to move it to another server which will be dedicated for the database. The database needs to be copied while in production, The new server is in the same network (Gbit lan). Do you need any other information?

Comment: I think the basic request here is *"Why cannot you use a real programming language?"*. The MongoDB shell is not intended for such purposes, so it would be better if you used something else. It would also be *better* if you edited your question to include more detail rather than trying to explain in comments. You can use comments to alert those who asked for information as to your changes in your question.